# Sumo and Traci : LastStepVehicleNumber does not update

Tags: sumo

I am using Sumo 0.27.1 and the Traci interface.

I am trying to get the number of vehicles occupying a lane and for that 
I use the following java code :

```
     Repository<Lane> lanes = conn.getLaneRepository();
     Map<String, Lane> laneMap = lanes.getAll();
     Iterator<Entry<String, Lane>> laneMapIterator = laneMap.entrySet().iterator();

     while(laneMapIterator.hasNext())
     {
         Entry<String, Lane> laneElem = laneMapIterator.next();
         Lane l = laneElem.getValue();

         if (!l.getID().startsWith(":"))
         {
             System.out.println("Lane ID: "+ l.getID() + " CO2: " + l.getCo2Emission());
             System.out.println("Lane ID: "+ l.getID() 
+ " Occupancy: " + l.getLastStepOccupancy() + " Vehicle Number: " 
+ l.getLastStepVehicleNumber());
         }
     }
```

Although there are many cars introduced in the simulation, I can the 
CO2, occupancy and vehicle number for just 3 of the lanes; and I get the 
same numbers during the simulation.

A similar code is working fine for getting individual vehicle meters, 
but does not work for lanes.

I there any update or reset command that I should explicitly take care of ?

Thanks in advance,

Vlad

Comment: Can you please share some of the surrounding code. Your snippet does not show where you do the simulation step.

Comment: This piece of code is called from another function that takes care of the simulation advance. This calling function calls : 
conn.nextSimStep();
then in a synchronized(conn) block calls the function containing the code I listed. (where conn is SumoTraciConnection)
I hope my explanation is understandable.
However, I managed to get the code to work by calling l.clearCache(); just before l.getCo2Emission() and the rest.